# Is it possible to release app as a iOS OPEN Beta?

Tags: ios, testflight, appstore-approval

Is it possible to release the iOS app as an open beta in App Store?
Use case: anyone can download the app through the Apps Store without having any registration ( same as play store beta release)

Comment: You can use TestFlight to distribute to a limited number of "testers".

Comment: Yes but I think it's not open for everyone right? I need to release an app for anyone can download without registering as a tester. Is it possible?

Comment: @anthonydonx what you wanna do can only be done with an Enterprise Program Account, https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/#:~:text=Apple%20Developer%20Enterprise%20Program.%20The%20Apple%20Developer%20Enterprise,systems%20or%20through%20a%20Mobile%20Device%20Management%20solution.

Comment: An enterprise program doesn't meet your needs as apps built under an enterprise program can only be made available to employees. Using TestFlight you can provide a public beta link that allows anyone to download and test

Comment: It seems to be no option to release the beta app as a public visible in-app store, without the use of a link or registration   @BenjaminWen

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "in App Store" bit. Only released versions are allowed in the App Store. Apple has higher standards for the App Store. Consumers expect to find fully functional apps. Beta and test apps are not permitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately your question is self-contradictory in the context of the App Store.

An app can either be *released* to the App Store or it can be in *test/beta* but it can't be both.

You can provide open beta access via a TestFlight link, but you need to find your own way of sharing this link (via your web site, for example).

Only fully functional apps will be approved for App Store release to ensure that users have a good experience with App Store apps. Any mention of "beta" or "test" will result in rejection.